Не подтягиваются переменные из .env
Имеется файл .env, в котором содержится одна переменная:
ID=ozonapi-msk-fbs-1

Пытаюсь подключить этот файл и использовать данную переменную в сервисе в файле docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.7"

x-app-envs: &app-envs
  NATS_URL: 'nats://nats:4222'

  GATEWAY_HOST: '${GATEWAY_HOST}'
  GATEWAY_PORT: '${GATEWAY_PORT}'

  S3_HOST: '${S3_HOST}'
  S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID: '${S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID}'
  S3_ACCESS_KEY: '${S3_ACCESS_KEY}'

  HTTP_NATS: '${HTTP_NATS}'

  # Redis
  REDIS_HOST: '${REDIS_HOST}'
  REDIS_PORT: '${REDIS_PORT}'
  REDIS_PASS: '${REDIS_PASS}'
  REDIS_DATABASE: '0'

services:
  ozonapi-msk-fbs-beta1:
    env_file: .env
    image: git******ru:5050/web/ozonapi:${TARGET_ENV}
    container_name: ${ID}-1-${TARGET_ENV}
    hostname: ozonapi-msk-fbs-beta1
    restart: always
    tty: true
    networks:
      ozonapi-network-beta1:
      redis:
    links:
      - "nats:nats"
    depends_on:
      - nats
    environment:
      <<: *app-envs
      CONFIGFILE: ${CONFIGFILE_MSK_FBS_1}
    labels:
      # portainer
      io.portainer.accesscontrol.teams: "MSA"
    volumes:
      - '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime'
      - '/var/log/ozonapitest:/app/logs'
    extra_hosts:
      - 'oraclerpc:10.32.0.24'

При деплое получаю 2 ошибки:
1)
time="2024-07-24T13:42:06Z" level=warning msg="The \"ID\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
2)
open /builds/web/ozonapi/.ci/dev/.env: no such file or directory
Такое ощущение, что я не правильно подключаю файл .env, соответственно он не передает переменную.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
